# NSFetchRequest with recursive criteria or Fetched Property

Tags: xcode4, recursion, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest, fetched-property

I have an entity type Node with recursive relationship called parent (inverse children). Now I want to get all entities which are directly or indirect below a certain node (i.e. branch root node) other entity.

Since I had no better idea, I created a entity type Position with a relationship node to entity type Node holding just one entity which is set to the certain branch root node.

In Node I want to create a Fetched Property isBelowBranchRootNode which should be true if node.parent == position.branchRootNode OR node.parent.isBelowBranchRootNode.

I cannot get it work. Any better ideas are much appreciated, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is a forest?  A set of root nodes with each root node having a tree of children?  If so, add a 'root' relationship to each node.  When you create a node as a child to parent, take the parent's root and give it to the new child too.